# How to import mainwindow (.ui file) using PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtgui, qmainwindow

I'm doing a python project and design its interface using PySide.
The problem is how can I import mainwindow (.ui file) from Qt Designer using PySide.
My class is inherited from QtGui.QMainWindow.

Thank you for your answer. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the top-level object in Qt Designer is named `MainWindow`.

When you use `pyside-uic` to generate the GUI module, it will create a class called `Ui_MainWindow`. It is this class that you need to import into your main application. The imported class has a `setupUi` method, which is used to inject the GUI into an instance of the top-level class from Qt Designer. So the basic code to do this should look something like this:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow.setupUi(self)
```

With that in place, you can access the widgets from Qt Designer like this:

```
       # connect a button to its handler
       self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked)
```

To run the application, you can do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I already use this method and it works. Thank you for answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [QUILoader class](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtUiTools/QUiLoader.html).

Namely, you would be using the "load" method which is documented [here](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtUiTools/QUiLoader.html#PySide.QtUiTools.PySide.QtUiTools.QUiLoader.load).

You can pass a QIODevice subclass as the first argument, so e.g. a QFile instance in which you open up the `.ui` file.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. I use pyside-uic instead to generate .py file from .ui file.
Thank you for your answer. I think it may useful for the others. ;) @Laszlo Papp